# Making 100 microseconds delay for STM32L0

Tags: timer, delay, hal

I need to create 100 microseconds delay for STM32L0 using HAL. I have HSE 12 MHz. APB1 timer clocks 12MHz.

```
htim6.Instance = TIM6;
htim6.Init.Prescaler = 1199;
htim6.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
htim6.Init.Period = 1;
```

When I have a loop of 50000 iterations which wraps calls to polling start/stop basic TIM6 timer (`HAL_TIM_Base_Start`), then I have 10 seconds delay instead of 5 seconds (The outer loop serves just for time scaling). Is it normal? I've expected 50000 * 100 microseconds = 5 seconds. Should I use another timer? I need +-10 microseconds delta. By the way, STM32L0 HAL does not contain "microseconds version" of `HAL_delay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 50,000 iterations which contain a check, and increase for a counter. If this would take e.g. 5 clock cycli per iteration, this results is 250,000 cycli. With a 12 MHz clock this is 20,8 ms, which is anyway above your requirement.

I don't see the 5 seconds extra delay, but even 20,8 ms is too much. It might be related to stack handling if you call a separate function, still than 5 seconds is a lot, but it will be (much) longer than 20,8 ms.

The solution would be to put the right value directly in the timer  prescaler/period and remove the counter/loop.

Comment: One more experiment has been done: when I set `htim6.Init.Prescaler = 119;` and `htim6.Init.Period = 10;` with 50000 iterations, then I got ~5 seconds delay. So, 10 steps with 10 microseconds were better than one 100 microseconds step

Comment: Outer loop was just for scaling, just to ensure that we have correct prescaler and period for such tiny delays. I've measured LED ON duration. By the way, should I decrease period by 1 for HAL struct?

Comment: I saw examples where indeed 1 was decreased from the maximum amount of loops... maybe to compensate for the overhead of the function call/return.